# Firebase Retrieve Data and return as array of type - my solution

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularfire2

I have recently started moving my iOS Application to also be a web app. I don't know if this implementation is correct. It works, but if someone could please let me know if it is correct.

Here is the function in my LicenceService:

```
get retriveLicences():Licence[] {

const licences: Licence[] = [];

this.afDatabase.list(this.basePath).valueChanges().subscribe((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach(element => {

    const licenceObject = <any>element

    licences.push(
      new Licence(
        licenceObject.name, 
        licenceObject.logoUrl, 
        licenceObject.maxUsers, 
        licenceObject.currentUserCount, 
        licenceObject.startDate, 
        licenceObject.endDate
      )
    );
  });
});

return licences
}
```

Comment: the problem I see with this is that is won't update because it is not using observable. But I don't want to put the logic for return a list of Licence outside of the service because them I will have to re-write it everytime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using rxjs operators, you can "transform" the snapshot before subscribing to it:

```
getLicences(): Observable<Licence[]> {
  return this.afDatabase
  .list(`/whatever`)
  .valueChanges()
  .map(licenceObjects => {
    return licenceObjects.map(licenceObject => new Licence(
      licenceObject.name, 
      licenceObject.logoUrl, 
      licenceObject.maxUsers, 
      licenceObject.currentUserCount, 
      licenceObject.startDate, 
      licenceObject.endDate
    ));
  })
}
```

However, if you create an interface with the exact variable names you have in your database, your life can become a lot easier cuz angularfire2 transforms it for you:

```
interface Licence {
  name: string;
  logoUrl: string;
  maxUsers: number;
  currentUserCount: number;
  startDate: number;
  endDate: number;
}

getLicences(): Observable<Licence[]> {
  return this.afDatabase.list<Licence>(`/whatever`).valueChanges();
}
```

So now in your component you can get the observable from the service and unwrap it with the async pipe or whatever way makes more sense to your app.
I hope this is helpful!